# What should be memory order for sequential load-store atomics when certain errors are acceptable

Tags: c++, c++11, concurrency, atomic, compare-and-swap

Assume that a user is twisting a knob on a MIDI controller, and the values are being sent to my program as increments and decrements to a stored value. Twisting the knob one way will send a series of decrements, their value depending upon the speed of rotation; twisting the other way increments. I want to keep the stored value (and the value emitted by the following function) to between 0 and 100. If one or a few of the messages get dropped, that's no big deal, but I don't want unexpected major changes in the value emitted by the `OffsetResult_` function.

My question then is--do the following memory order directives look correct? The clearest one for me is the `compare_exchange_strong`. The program is using that as a `store` that can fail, so it seems that release memory ordering applies.

Can I even go to `std::memory_order_relaxed` since the major concern is just the atomicity of the changes to storedV, rather than remembering each change to storedV?

Is there a general way to look at combined load/store functions to see whether it should be acquire, release, or sequentially consistent?

```
class ChannelModel {
    ChannelModel():currentV{0}{};
    int OffsetResult_(int diff) noexcept;
  private:
    atomic<int> storedV;
};

int ChannelModel::OffsetResult_(int diff) noexcept {
  int currentV = storedV.fetch_add(diff, std::memory_order_acquire) + diff;
  if (currentV < 0) {//fix storedV unless another thread has already altered it
    storedV.compare_exchange_strong(currentV, 0, std::memory_order_release, std::memory_order_relaxed);
    return 0;
  }
  if (currentV > 100) {//fix storedV unless another thread has already altered it
    storedV.compare_exchange_strong(currentV, 100, std::memory_order_release, std::memory_order_relaxed);
    return 100;
  }
  return currentV;
}
```

Note that the actual code is much more complex, and it is reasonable to believe that the response to each message from the controller will take long enough that this function will, on occasion, be called by two threads at nearly the same time.

Comment: 1. `fetch_add(...) + diff` adds `diff` twice, doesn't it? 2. Won't that `fetch_add` result in `storedV = storedV + diff` which might be `< 0` or `> 100` which in turn may then be visible to other threads?

Comment: fetch_add returns the *original value* and stores the *result* of the addition. So, to be able to use the result correctly in the function without doing another fetch to the atomic (and perhaps having concurrency issues), I'm adding diff to the value fetched as well.

Comment: Yes, the out of bounds value could be visible to other threads, but that's not a major issue, as the function will never return an out of bounds value. So the user won't notice an issue, other than perhaps a very slight delay when starting to move the controller in the opposite direction. My goal is to have each thread have an internally consistent view of the value--so that's why most of the work is done with a temporary variable.

Comment: This is a slightly different problem domain, but of interest to you may be [CRDTs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conflict-free_replicated_data_type)

Answer (score 0):

I will make the assumption that `currentV` is a local variable in `OffsetResult_`.
For some reason, it is initialized in the class constructor, but not defined as a class variable.

You are changing the value of `storedV` with `fetch_add` and then adjust for possible errors with `compare_exchange_strong`.
That is not correct... `compare_exchange_strong` is used here as a conditional `store`. Only if another thread does not changes the value, `storedV` will be updated.
The memory orderings you specify are incorrect..  In general, `release` ordering is used with an atomic `store` to indicate that data is 'released',
ie. made available to another thread that will `load` from the same atomic using `acquire` ordering. `release` and `acquire` ordering form a run-time relationship and always come in pairs.
That relationship is missing in your code when `currentV` is within its defined range since you never perform a `release` operation.

It is not clear why you want to specify orderings. Note that you don't have to set memory ordering in which case case the (safer) default (`std::memory_order_seq_cst`) will be used.
Whether or not a weaker ordering is correct depends on the data it synchronizes between threads.
With no data dependency, using `std::memory_order_relaxed` might be correct, but that context is missing in the code.
However, since the atomic is associated with a knob value, it is likely that twisting the knob will result in some action that involves other data.
I would not attempt to optimize with weaker memory orderings here. Chances are there will be no benefit at all since the Read-Modify-Write call (`compare_exchange_x`) is already 
relatively expensive. Also, if using a weaker memory ordering introduces a bug, it will be *very* hard to debug.

You can use `std::compare_exchange_weak` for the adjustment without losing updates:

```
int ChannelModel::OffsetResult_(int diff) noexcept {
  int updatedV;

  int currentV = storedV.load();

  do {
    updatedV = currentV + diff;

    if (updatedV > 100)
        updatedV = 100;
    else if (updatedV < 0)
        updatedV = 0;

  } while (!storedV.compare_exchange_weak(currentV, updatedV));

  return updatedV;
}
```

The key is that `compare_exchange_weak` will only (atomically) update `storedV` if it is still (or again) equal to `currentV`.
If that check fails, it will iterate through the loop again.
Used in a loop, `compare_exchange_weak` (which may fail spuriously) is a better choice than `compare_exchange_strong`.

Memory ordering is a complex topic, [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Atomic/GCCMM/AtomicSync) is a good overview.

Comment: I'm not concerned about losing updates, thus no need to go to a loop for compare_exchange. interesting comment about memory orderings. With the Intel processors, is there any real benefit to fussing around with memory ordering?

Comment: To fix my last comment--I'm asking about memory ordering for compare_exchange. Sounds like it is expensive enough that changes in memory ordering aren't worth it. Is that correct?

Comment: @rsjaffe That is exactly right.. The RMW is expensive because it has to lock the bus in order to synchronize with other cores accessing the data. In your code, for `fetch_add` and `compare_exchange_strong` you are going to see object code like `lock xadd` and `lock cmpxchg` respectively. On X86, there is no difference between what you use and `seq_cst` ordering